# Parent view draw child view efficient

Tags: android, android-layout, view, ondraw

For example, top level LinearLayout view has 300 child view. But device screen dimension only show 11 child view once. How android compute how many child views can show once? How a view know that it will be draw? 

**Edited**
In my work, one case like this:
An parent LinearLayout view may be has hundreds child view. In order to better performance , my solution like this:like lazy load.

1. List list = new ArrayList();//contain entity object that use construct View object
2. Default load 5 child view.
3. Parent LinearLayout view last child view is custom Loading View, I have override it`s onDraw() method. If loading View is draw, that means i need get next 5 child view(get next 5 object from list,and create correspond view).

I want to know how android framework handle this case?

Comment: read MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED from here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html

Answer (score 0):

> An parent LinearLayout view may be has hundreds child view. In order
>   to better performance , my solution like this:like lazy load.

`LinearLayout` with(possible) hundreds of child views kind of contradicts *better performance*. I think what you're looking for is a `ListView` with an endless adapter(a simple google search will show how to implement it, not something that difficult). This adapter will start loading views(with a loading view showing while the new content loads) as soon as you get to the last loaded element.

If you still want to use a `LinearLayout`:

If you just want to make the `LinearLayout` fill the content of the screen when it's first laid out you could post a `Runnable` on one of your views in the `onCreate` method (if this is where you'll first populate the `LinearLayout`). In that `Runnable` find the height of the `LinearLayout` and compare it with the combined height of its currently present children. If the combined child height is smaller then the `LinearLayout` height then add more views to compensate.

If the `LinearLayout` is in a `ScrollView` and you want to add additional children when the loading view becomes visible then monitor the scrolling of the `ScrollView` and when the loading view becomes visible add new children. Seeing when the loading view becomes visible would be done by checking how much the user has scrolled compared with the combined height of the currently present children of the `LinearLayout`.

**Initial response:**

Your question is a bit ambiguous regarding what you want to know. If you have a specific problem you should start with that.

> For example, top level LinearLayout view has 300 child view. But
>   device screen dimension only show 11 child view once.

Please don't get yourself in a scenario like this. That number of views is to big an will result in poor performance or even the app crashing if you run out of memory(as all those views will be kept in memory).

> How android compute how many child views can show once?

Each `View` and `ViewGroup` has the `onMeasure` method to measure itself and its children if available. The `LinearLayout` will have its `onMeasure` method called and in this method it will measure its children(with the measure `method`) giving them some suggestions on how big should they be(the `LinearLayout` receives some suggestions on how big it should be from its parent). If you want to see how this is done have a look at the source code of the `LinearLayout`.

> How a view know that it will be draw?

I don't understand what you want to know. To draw the view on the screen its `onDraw` method will be called.

Comment: thanks you answer. I want to know the detail that android how handle this. I see LinearLayout source code, not find the compute logic.

Comment: @boiledwater If you look at the source code of The `LinearLayout` you'll see in the `onMeasure` **how** it measures its chidlren. The `onMeasure` callback will be called by the system whenever there is the need to show/reshow the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Have u used scroll bar inside the  top level LinearLayout view  and add child view on that layout that's simple...